# ASP menu disappears

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Default ASP Menu pops up when using mouse-over on Computer. On modern touch systems that could be a problem. On mobile app, the mouse-over does not exist and if user clicks on the ASP menu, the menu pops up but disappears before user can select menu child items.

How to allow touch-screen users to work with ASP menu?

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:Menu ID="cmbMyAccount" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DisappearAfter="5000">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="My Account" Value="My Account" Selectable="False">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="My Orders" Value="My Orders" NavigateUrl="~/MyOrders/index.aspx" />
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Wish List" Value="Wish List" NavigateUrl="~/MyOrders/WishList.aspx" />
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="My Profile" Value="My Profile" NavigateUrl="~/MyProfile/index.aspx" />
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Live demo: http://www.fscan.com/temp/ButtonTest.aspx

Comment: Please show your RENDERED HTML + CSS, not your server-side .NET code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easyiest way I found was to set the menu item to selectable:

```
 Selectable="True" NavigateUrl="../Contact/index.aspx"
```

Whole menu looks like this:

```
<asp:Menu ID="cmbContact" runat="server" CssClass="NoUnderLine" Orientation="Horizontal" DisappearAfter="5000">
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle ForeColor="#FDFDFD" CssClass="LightText" />
                        <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#DFDFDF" />
                        <DynamicMenuItemStyle ForeColor="#202020" CssClass="SelectionItem " />
                        <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#ADD8E7" />
                        <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact" Value="Contact" Selectable="True" NavigateUrl="../Contact/index.aspx">
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Ticket Service" Value="Ticket Service" NavigateUrl="../ContactTicket/index.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Phone Service" Value="Phone Service" NavigateUrl="../Contact/index.aspx#phone"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Email" Value="Email" NavigateUrl="../Contact/index.aspx#email"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                        </Items>
                    </asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Modernizr to detect touch screen devices. http://modernizr.com/
Than you can override dropdown menu style to stop hidding it.

```
.touch #cmbMyAccount:hover ul.dynamic { display:block !important; }
```

You can use touch detection in js also:

```
if (Modernizr.touch) { 
    // Sys.WebForms.Menu function override
}
```

Comment: I've tried that way but the menu does not work with by using 'display:block !important' I've also tried to read the Modernizr.com page but it is based on div menus and did not work on the ASP menu, even if ASP contains html output with div elements. Have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

The menu could be disappearing due to `post back` of the page

Simply set the `navigateURL` property of main menu items to "`javascript:return false;`" so that the pages does not `post back` and your drop down menu does not disappear.